# module not detected django production

Tags: python, django, postgresql, collectstatic

I'm trying to deploy my Django app onto a DigitalOcean VPS. I set everything up and was about to run `python manage.py collectstatic` when I hit this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/demo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/demo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/demo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/demo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/demo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named embed_video
```

The problem is that I already installed `embed_video` (Django's app name for [this](https://github.com/jazzband/django-embed-video) application) using `pip install django-embed-video`. My problem is that the app isn't being detected.

If it helps, I'm implementing PostgreSQL as the production database, and SQLite as the development database, and I'm also using nginx and gunicorn as part of the process.

Since people asked, here is my `settings.py`

```
import os
from os import path
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
PROJECT_DIR_PATH = path.dirname(path.normpath(path.abspath(__file__)))


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'about.apps.AboutConfig',
        'forms.apps.FormsConfig',
        'resources.apps.ResourcesConfig',
        'contact.apps.ContactConfig',
        'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'embed_video',
        'bootstrap3',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'nydkcd11.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                                'django.template.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'nydkcd11.wsgi.application'





#PRODUCTION DATABASE
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'databse',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]




LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'




#PRODUCTION
STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/myenv/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Which version of python do you use?

Comment: 2.7 it s written in stacktrace

Comment: post some part of your settings file

Comment: Which part of settings.py do you need?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the module is correctly installed in Python, you can first try tp check with `pip list` to see the list of modules installed in python.

Then try to import the module manually, put this in the console:

`python 
import embed_video`

and check if there isn't any error when you click return after embed_video.

you have more that a Python installation on your Pc???, are you using virtual environment???, all these things could be the root of your error.